# ibm apiconnect developer toolkit slow

Tags: performance, apiconnect

Why the apic command is so slow? I am the only one? What should I do to understand the problem? It is present on my computer, on our deployment server, on the pcs of the other people working on this.

```
$ time apic help
Error: Il comando `help` non è valido.

real    0m15.852s
user    0m0.045s
sys     0m0.076s
```

or

```
$ time apic -v
API Connect: v5.0.6.1 (apiconnect: v2.5.17)

real    0m14.710s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.091s
```

Comment: which OS are you using? I noticed that in MAC OS it is really slow, but when working on an Ubuntu based OS it is faster

Comment: I am using Windows. Checked on linux and it is actually faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIC toolkit for APIC v5 is based on Node.js framework. It uses a lot of modules that need to be loaded when `apic` command is called. 
So the speed is dependant on disk speed (but also on CPU & memory). 
My test shows that initial load takes about 9 seconds on my 2 years old laptop:

```sh
$ time apic -v
API Connect: v5.0.8.4-iFix (apiconnect: v2.8.29)

real    0m9.206s
user    0m0.092s
sys     0m0.091s
```

This is test using Git Bash on Win 10 machine.

Second try (when a lot of files are cached) is 2 seconds faster:

```sh
$ time apic -v
API Connect: v5.0.8.4-iFix (apiconnect: v2.8.29)

real    0m6.625s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.090s
```

Good news is that new version of the `apic` CLI toolkit is written in Golang and compiled native to the platform. 
This one is fast. By all standards. It is also more capable too.

```sh
time apic version
APIConnect toolkit c81e13c07d3c2c7730827610fcaf08bbec88fe04 (Built 2020-02-10T23:21:01Z) (Tag o.c3148da-g.c81e13c)

real    0m0.192s
user    0m0.141s
sys     0m0.094s
```

This test is done on the same laptop but using Ubuntu under WSL. 
I would suggest to either migrate to v2018 or use faster machine with modern SSD (not all SSDs are the same).